# Why is a 16:9 ratio recommended for hero images?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm trying to determine the best size for a hero image on my website's homepage. I keep running into the suggestion of making sure it's a 16:9 ratio. But why? Because it matches the proportions of a video? If I'm not using a video on the homepage, why would this matter?

And while I'm at it, the dimension suggestions I find vary widely. Here in late January, 2021, is there a recommended size for hero images?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. It might be a better fit for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe because it's the aspect ratio currently used by most monitors?

Comment: But in a responsive design world, the browser window's aspect ratio is unpredictable and ever-changing. The dimensions of the browser window will rarely match that of the monitor unless the user selects full-screen mode, so why try and emulate the monitor's aspect ratio?